# QGIS expressions don't evaluate as expected

Tags: qgis, debugging

I am using QGIS with a vector layer and the attribute table stored at this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K7rRdlcSheclJ6MqzpBNwSZei911WDV1Bl2zBGV38-s/edit?usp=sharing

I then have the following code:

```
CASE

/*Kieran Winner*/
WHEN "r_Kieran" > "r_Wynne" 
        THEN ramp_color('PCMarg', scale_linear(("r_Kieran"/"r_TOTAL"-"r_Possian"/"r_TOTAL"),  0,  1, 0, 1))     
ELSE color_rgb(64, 224, 208)
END
```

Here's the problem:
**The code evaluates incorrectly.**

Take row 15 of the attribute table for example. (Where PD_Number=14)
You would expect that the condition would evaluate TRUE since
"r_Kieran"=397 and "r_Wynne"=225.

But, it evaluates FALSE in QGIS, as indicated by the colour that is displayed on the map!

I've spent hours simplifying code, and pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: If I add a column which is `"r_Kieran" > "r_Wynne"` I get a "True" (1) value for the row with PD_NUMBER=14, and if I make a new column with your expression I get the right colour for it too. In short, I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Can you confirm that those columns are of a numeric type?

Comment: Echoing DPSSpatial, if the columns are not numeric in your original attribute table, try wrapping your relevant column references with to_int() (e.g. to_int("r_Kieran"))

Comment: Ok Seems like PD_NUMBER=14 evaluates True now. Have a look at PD_NUMBER=10 it seems to evaluate false, but it should be True.

Comment: Ok So adding surrounding the column references with the to_int() function has solved the problem. Can someone explain how to fix the original attribute table so that the data is in integers?

Comment: How are you creating your layer? I downloaded the spreadsheet from google docs **as a CSV** and read it using QGIS "Delimited Text Layer" - all the `r_` columns are recognised as integers.

Comment: If it's not a CSV but a shapefile or similar, try changing the data type using Refactor Layers under the processing toolbox, creating a temp layer, checking that it works and then saving over your original data. If you're reading off an xlsx it's more tricky, you are probably better off saving as a CSV.

Comment: Its a shapefile joined with a CSV. The data that is not reading as integers is from the CSV